# Laravel accessors não funciona com campo separado por _ com uma letra

Tags: laravel-4

Quando faço uso do accessor com um campo ex.: "nome_completo", coloco no model:
**public function getNomeCompletoAttribute($value)** funciona perfeitamente.
Quando tenho um campo "endereco_c", coloco no model: **public function getEnderecoCAttribute($value)** não funciona, a impressão que tenho é que não encontra o campo.

Comment: Fiz o teste aqui e tudo funcionou normalmente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existe uma informação errônea na pergunta:

Os métodos de acesso do  `Laravel` não necessitam de parâmetro.

Exemplo:

```
public function getEnderecoCAttribute()
{
       return 'Endereço C';
}
```

E também eu fiz os testes no `Laravel 4` e `Laravel 5`: ambos funcionaram corretamente.

O que você chama de "não funciona"?

O valor está retornando `NULL`?

Isso pode ser porque você está retornando algo que está `Null`, ou porque não existe o model (acidentalmente já adicionei um método num model, pensando que era outro).

Enfim, a funcionalidade funciona como esperado.

O teste que pode ser feito é você chamar o método diretamente

```
 $model->getEnderecoCAttribute();
```

O que isso retorna? Talvez aí esteja a resposta do seu problema.